# Setting up ArcPad applet (Python) that calls arcgisscripting?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, installation, arcpad, arcgis-runtime

I've been asked to support a legacy script that was "made" (read: found) by a former coworker.

My python skills are pretty basic, so I went right to installing the applet like I would for a VBS applet, got an error saying no python, so I put on python, similar error, I read about python win32, and got that on all nicely matched up with bit (32) and version (2.7.7).  Ran the applet, and it starts python and does some string manipulations to create an output name so I know Python is working, then it crashes on "import arcgisscripting".

Now I have enough Python experience to know that's the usual call you make in the Desktop environment... A quick check and sure enough the laptop where this applet currently works has a copy of ArcGIS on it...

I have read in a few places that a ArcGIS runtime SDK might solve the problem, but which one...?  Does python even care?  How do you buy a runtime sdk license and how much?

Many many thanks for any help at all.  At this point I'm open to any suggestions.

Comment: what is your version of ArcGIS ?

Comment: In the event you want to tweak it to work with ArcPy instead (which I'd do personally, but "pretty basic" python skills might not want to), [this checklist can be helpful for upgrading](http://gisstudio.wordpress.com/2011/12/30/things-to-keep-in-mind-when-switching-from-arcgisscripting-to-arcpy/).

Comment: I agree with @Erica I would start by replacing references to the older _arcgisscripting_ geoprocessor with _arcpy_. +1 for that check list link that is a very useful starting point when upgrading a python script.